# where does the file gets stored if I placed in getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() directory? Will it increase app size?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

```
Future<void> downloadFile() async{
    Dio dio = Dio() ;
    try{
      var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      print('DIR is :${dir}');
      await dio.download(pdfUrl, "${dir.path}/sample.pdf",onReceiveProgress: (rec,total){
        print('rec:${rec},total:${total}');

        setState(() {
          downloading=true ;
          progressString =((rec / total) * 100).toStringAsFixed(0) + "%" ;
        });
      });
    }catch(e){
      print(e);
    }

    setState(() {
      downloading = false;
      progressString = "Completed";
    });
    print("Download completed");
  }
```

I want to store my downloaded pdf for offline use, how can I implement it? How can I save in downloads/(sample.pdf) local folder and can retrieve files whenever offline?

Answer (score 1):

On iOS, this uses the NSDocumentDirectory API. Consider using getApplicationSupportDirectory instead if the data is not user-generated.

On Android, this uses the getDataDirectory API on the context. Consider using getExternalStorageDirectory instead if data is intended to be visible to the user.

So I don't know the App size means? if u download a file to app's dir , this will obvious increase app cache or some other size , but will not increate apk size.

Comment: By app size I meant apk size.

Comment: So you won't increase apk size at all .